# Illustrator: brushes/stroke not in the center of the path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, brush

Does anyone know how to center my newly created brushes with the path? When I increase the stroke it simply goes everywhere.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. With the path selected, open the appearance panel and check if there is an effect added. If so, delete it.

Comment: Kinda need to see the brush artwork on its own, as well as the brush options.

Comment: I checked the appearance, but there is nothing to delete and I have also tried out different brushes, even the ones that are already provided, with the same results. I have also tried the calligraphic brush, but it is not giving me the effect I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by playing with the options of that particular brush:

> To change the options for a brush, double-click the brush in the
> Brushes panel. Set the brush options and click OK. If the current
> document contains brushed paths that use the modified brush, a message
> appears. Click Apply To Strokes to change pre-existing strokes.

- Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/brushes.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried to play with different settings from the brush, but whatever I do, it still moves away from the path... odd..

Answer (score 0):

The way I replicated your issue was by messing with the mask of the brush.

Use the menu>view>outline to see it.

If it's the case, just delete that mask and make a brush again.

[image]